# Why do Swift's Date time intervals ignore leap seconds?

Tags: swift, datetime, nscalendar

[30 June 2012 had a leap second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second). As such it lasted 86401 seconds.
However, in the following Swift code, `timeInterval` is 86400.
How come?

```swift
let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
let date = formatter.date(from: "2012-06-30T00:00:00Z")!
let dayAfter = formatter.date(from: "2012-07-01T00:00:00Z")!
let timeInterval = date.distance(to: dayAfter)
```

(ps: in what context did I write this code? It was just about having fun with code. I was trying to write confusing code results, but I was disappointed by this attempt at trying to be smart)

Comment: I'm not aware of any standard time API in any programming language that does anything other than ignore leap seconds.

Comment: Interesting: https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/issues/416

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basis for Apple date and time APIs and system implementations is the [ICU library](https://icu.unicode.org/home), and the underpinnings for most of the results you see depends on ICU behavior. Notably, [ICU doesn't support or consider the existence of leap seconds](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/datetime/timezone/#overview):

> For historical reasons, the reference point is Greenwich, England. Local time in Greenwich is referred to as Greenwich Mean Time, or GMT. (This is similar, but not precisely identical, to Universal Coordinated Time, or UTC. We use the two terms interchangeably in ICU since ICU does not concern itself with either leap seconds or historical behavior.)

As such, Apple platforms also don't represent historical (or future) leap seconds in any way in APIs; systems *effectively* deal with leap seconds via [NTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol), and simply set their clocks appropriately, but querying for leap seconds like this won't yield anything.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! This surprises me a little, to be honest. I can understand why they did that (simplicity), but that's still a little disappointing, given that it punts the responsibility to API consumers, who are even less equipped to figure this out for themselves. Do you have any suggestions for how OP should proceed from here?

Comment: @Alexander It sounds like there aren't any next steps for OP, who was simply exploring the APIs — though if you need to somehow deal with leap seconds in a meaningful way historically, it will really depend on what you need to do and how. Specifically, many systems deal with leap seconds very differently (some smear time, some leap discontinuously), and it depends on what exactly you need to know about the existence of that leap second.

Comment: (e.g., do you need to know exactly what a wall clock showed at a given number of seconds from the start of the epoch, taking into account leap seconds? That'd be a very different exploration from "how many absolute seconds have passed since this point in time, accounting for leap seconds?")

Comment: In general, leap seconds _don't_ need to taken into account, since under many interpretations, they don't actually "exist". They are adjustments made to world clocks to account for the specific perturbations of Earth's rotation to keep time aligned with solar time, but in most cases, it's entirely sufficient to know "what time is it right now?", which NTP handles.

Comment: That makes sense. Bless the unix epoch. 1 second per second, no questions asked, haha (if I'm over-simplifying and there's actually a "gotcha" I don't know about, please don't tell me, I'm enjoying this over-simplified ignorant bliss )

Comment: @Alexander We're all time travelers, hurtling into the future at a blistering 1 second per second 